# Is onServiceConnected only called after Service onCreate?

Tags: android, service, bind, onserviceconnected

In my current Android Project, I am starting a Service via `startService()`, then afterwards I am binding to the Service with `bindService()`. *(I do this because I want to have a started Service I am able to communicate with, nevermind)*

After the Context is bound to the Service, usually `onServiceConnected()` of my `ServiceConnection` *(wich I created earlier)* is called if i understood this right.

Can I assume, that `onServiceConnected()` is only called after **all of my code** in the `onCreate` of my Service is executed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I assume, that onServiceConnected() is only called after all of my
>   code in the onCreate of my Service is executed?

Yes you can.

According to the [service lifecycle diagram](http://developer.android.com/images/service_lifecycle.png) `onBind()` is not called until after `onCreate()` has completed.

The documentation states that the system calls `onServiceConnected()` to deliver the `IBinder` returned by the service's `onBind()` method.

Therefore `onCreate()` is completed before `onServiceConnected()` is called since it is dependent on the return value of `onBind()` which occurs after `onCreate()`. You can also see this in the diagram where it says "Clients are bound to service".